# Cloud Foundry css file returns 502 Bad Gateway: Registered endpoint failed to handle the request

Tags: spring-boot, cloud-foundry, pivotal-web-services

I pushed my spring boot app with `VUE frontend` to `Cloud Foundry`. When I send request to static file (css/img/js) such as `https://bd-contacts-gateway.cfapps.io/js/chunk-vendors.8b8c1d1d.js`

I get

> 502 Bad Gateway: Registered endpoint failed to handle the request.

In my spring boot app I have static files in `src/main/resources/js`, `src/main/resources/css, src/main/resources/img`

This is my `manifest.yml` when pushing to CF

```
---

applications:

- name: bd-contacts-gateway

  memory: 1024M

  buildpack: staticfile_buildpack

  routes:

  - route: bd-contacts-gateway.cfapps.io
```

EDIT:

This is extract from cf logs when calling swagger-ui URL:

```
2019-09-11T11:34:04.60+0200 [RTR/10] OUT bd-contacts-gateway.cfapps.io
- [2019-09-11T09:34:04.491+0000] "GET /swagger-ui.html HTTP/1.1" 502 0 67 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.1.2 Safari/605.1.15" "10.10.66.115:63512" "10.10.148.61:61150" x_forwarded_for:"80.242.35.228, 10.10.66.115" x_forwarded_proto:"https" vcap_request_id:"6ccc526a-00c6-4a80-46c1-4c4eee6fcab7" response_time:0.115106066 app_id:"b5dc7fb4-a52a-4997-93cb-9ed40a158bcc" app_index:"0" x_b3_traceid:"3b50452335bafcf9" x_b3_spanid:"3b50452335bafcf9" x_b3_parentspanid:"-" b3:"3b50452335bafcf9-3b50452335bafcf9"
```

Comment: Do you get any successful responses from your app? 502 usually means your app didn't respond to the request fast enough. It would be good to turn up the log level or add additional logging to your app to confirm that the request does make it to your app and to log how quickly your app responds. It's a static file so it should be super fast, but you don't know unless you check. Also, capture the output from `cf logs`, as you'll get a log message from `RTR` which indicates how long it waited to service the request. You can use that to help understand what happened as well.

Comment: Thanks for comment. The app works fine when calling REST-API methods such as /login or /controller/findAll etc. In localhost I can access swagger-ui with no problems. When I deploy the app to CF and access swagger-ui URL I get HTTP  502 Bad Gateway -  Registered endpoint failed to handle the request. Can there be problem with HTTP running on localhost and HTTPS running on Cloud Foundry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I had to add remote_ip_header and protocol_header in my application-cloud.yml properties. Like this:

```
server:
  port: 8080
  tomcat:
    remote_ip_header: x-forwarded-for
    protocol_header: x-forwarded-proto

eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://bd-contacts-eureka.cfapps.io/eureka/
  instance:
    hostname: ${vcap.application.uris[0]}
    nonSecurePort: 80
```